# PrimeNG Table "currentPageReportTemplate" i18n localization

Tags: internationalization, primeng, angular-i18n, primeng-table

The following code, which works on all the other placeholders (dropdowns, etc.) doesn't work.
When running the translated version to text is cut after 1st word, eg.
It should be `Záznamy {first} až {last} z celkového počtu {totalRecords}` but instead only `Záznamy` is shown.

```
currentPageReportTemplate="Records {first} to {last} from {totalRecords}"
i18n-currentPageReportTemplate="@@Paginator text in Mentor/Students"
```